# Book - High tech civilization comes into contact with low-tech world of horse nomads, romance occurs

Tags: story-identification, books

Some time ago I read a series of books about a high-tech civilization coming into contact with a low-tech world of horse nomads.  A female lead character who was an explorer/anthropologist falls for a clan leader.  It would have been published in the 90's and it involved gates.  I never finished the series, because there are far too many good books to read and only one of me, but now it's bugging me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and edit in any more details, that would be great.

Comment: I'm assuming we can immediate rule out Robert Adams' *Horseclans* series - while there's a possible match to high-tech meets low-tech (in that the setting is a post-apocalyptic Earth, where most of the people we meet have regressed to a pre-Industrial-Revolution (at least) state); I don't recall any "gates".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could this be the eponymous first novel of the *[Jaran](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1537563.Jaran)* series? It was written by Kate Elliott and published in 1992.

[image: Book Cover - Jaran]

> Tess had been cursed by an accident of birth, cursed to be the sister of the one man honored by the alien conquerors of human-run space. Her brother, Charles Soerensen, the leader of Earth’s rebellion, had been given a dukedom after his defeat and now ruled over far-distant worlds. And Tess was his only heir, a position and a responsibility she was not yet willing to assume. So she fled to a world in her brother’s domain, a world where she was soon to discover—the alien conquerors were themselves involved in some covert and dangerous mission.
>
> And despite herself, Tess was suddenly forced to become both player and pawn in an interstellar game of intrigue and politics, caught between protecting her brother’s interests, and her own growing involvement with Ilya, the leader of the nomadic tribe with whom she had taken shelter. But it soon became apparent to Tess that whether Charles or the aliens were the victors here, Ilya and his people were balanced at a crucial point in their history—a point at which they must either learn to adapt to the incursions of more advanced civilizations or, by remaining rooted in their own traditions, face inevitable extinction.

The part that does not match is that she travels by shuttle, not via a gate, although Elliott's *[Crossroads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44731-crossroads)* series employs "Gates" in its titles. Also, if I can trust [the review of the series](https://www.sfsite.com/09a/jar40.htm) I found, Tess is not an anthropologist or researcher, but closer to a runaway princess.

I found this series by searching for *science fiction book series horse nomads romance*

Comment: This is it!  Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: @PibbleMomma: Glad I could help. And welcome to the site, incidentally! :) Hang around and you'll learn wondrous things. Wondrous things...

Answer (score 3):

No gates involved, but if you mistake the vault door hiding the cryosleep facility for a "gate" this is very similar to *Escape to Challenge*, the first book of the *[Moondark Saga](https://donmcquinn.com/books/moondarksaga/)* (and originally the first part of *Warrior* before it was broken up into smaller books for the ebook publishing).  Publication date is right (1989), horse nomads (Gan Moondark's "Dog People" were every bit of that), high tech folks meeting them (sleepers from before the nuclear/biological/chemical holocaust), and traveler/priestess who falls in love with one the few folks from Gan's tribe who remained loyal to him after he was framed for a murder.

[image: Book Cover - Escape to Challenge]